censorship unlock results into debug port fail and JTAG reset
I was trying to unlock JTAG and debug the software and results into either debug port fail or target reset. The steps I followed.
SYStem.RESet
SYStem.BdmClock 16.0MHz
SYStem.DETECT CPU
SYStem.Option.ResBreak OFF
SYStem.Option.WaitReset 3s
SYStem.Option KEYCODE 0x12345678 0x12345678 0x12345678 0x12345678 0x12345678 0x12345678 0x12345678 0x12345678
System.Option ResetMode FUNCtional
SYStem.Option.WATCHDOG OFF
SYStem.Up

My expectation is after SYStem.Up I should be able to flash and debug the software but after SYStem.Up if I'm trying attach i'm in running(Reset) or debug port fail

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. Then come back and [edit] your question to clarify. -- Many MCUs have protection measures. What is your specific target? Did you check or do you know about the protection state of your target? Did you try with another unit?

Many targets won't let you modify the watchdog setting without reset or power on+off.
